# Need help to clean/organize sonata-project dependencies in composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I'm using the great sonata admin bundle on my projects.
But for a few months, I got problems with the dependencies when updating using composer. I needed to change version declaration, but it keeps giving me errors.

I took a look on the sonata doc but it gives no help on versions.

So I'm asking here if someone could give me the correct configuration in the composer file to get all of sonata bundle working together.

Here is my composer.json

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "winzou/console-bundle": "1.*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "~2.0@dev"
```

My Symfony version is 2.3.8

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post what dependencies requiers composer while updating? E.g. what error do you get?

Comment: `- sonata-project/cache-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/cache ~1.0@dev -> no matching package found.` is the error I get now (without any modifications). The thing is, I had errors a month ago. I needed to change versions in some bundles so I thought my dependencies config was kind of messed-up with wrong versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working composer configuration for sonata bundles and Symfony **2.3.9**:

```
{
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/cache": "~1.0@dev",
    "sonata-project/block-bundle": "@dev",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.0",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/exporter": "1.3.*"
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of Symfony 2.3.9? Did you consider NOT using development versions to get a stable release into your software?

Comment: @Sven sorry? 2.3.9 is a stable version of 2.3.x branch. http://symfony.com/download

Comment: Also this configuration works with `minimum-stability` set to **stable** in the composer root section.

Comment: You are not including Symfony in any version, so how do you ensure it is that version?

Comment: Well, actually, your list of dependencies do not work for me. Composer complains about not being able to find `sonata-project/cache ~1.0@dev`, which is a dependency of `sonata-project/cache-bundle dev-master`.

Comment: @Sven that's because I've included only sonata packages in my answer, which OP need.

Comment: @Sven yes, sorry, I've forget to include `sonata-project/cache` in additional to `cache-bundle`. Just tested it on my project, it worked. Updated the answer.

Comment: I think the sonata-project/cache-bundle messed it up. With the commit six days ago that put several cache classes into sonata-project/cache, they created an unresolvable dependency. The answer should not be to manually fix this, but to not use dev-master until they fix it.

Comment: Why do you think they messed up? They just added a new dependency to the dev-master (which actually is a stable branch). End-user only have to updated his composer. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Thanks for this guys, everything is working and no dependencies problems. I got a question though : is there a good way to update dependencies without screwing everything ? I mean, I think that's normal and required to `composer update` sometimes to get bundles updates. But I also thing it could mess it all... (at least, that's what happened to me).
One more point : composer updated Symfony to 2.3.10 and no problem.